# Binding MVVM CheckBox inside a Listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to use the pattern MVVM inside my application Windows Phone. But i have a problem with this one to bind a CheckBox who's inside a listbox.

This is my .xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstbTagsFavoris"  SelectionChanged="favoris_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,10,0,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Foreground="#555" Background="Red" Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Content="{Binding Categories}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class CategorieViewModel
{
    private List<string> _Categories = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return _Categories;
        }

        set
        {
            _Categories = value;
        }
    }

    public void GetCategories()
    {
        Categories = GlobalVar._GlobalItem.SelectMany(a => a.tags)
            .OrderBy(t => t)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
    }
```

In my xaml.cs :

```
            CategorieViewModel c = new CategorieViewModel();
        c.GetCategories();
        this.DataContext = c;
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

do this.

```
public class CategorieViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _Categories = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Categories
    { 
        get
        {
           return _Categories;
        }

        set
        {
        _Categories = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Categories");
        }
    }

    public void GetCategories()
    {
        Categories = GlobalVar._GlobalItem.SelectMany(a => a.tags)
           .OrderBy(t => t)
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstbTagsFavoris" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectionChanged="favoris_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,10,0,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Foreground="#555" Background="Red" Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Content="{Binding}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You need to add ItemsSource property for Listbox, not directly to the checkbox

This will surely help you..

Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It didn't change anything, but thanks for INotifyPropertyChanged :)